# Does the determinant as transformation of area interpretation hold for any closed curve in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

A way to interpret the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix is as the signed area of the parellogram  generated having sides as the transformed unit vectors. This made me wonder, suppose we have a closed algebraic curve $F(x,y)=0$, then would the ratio of the area of this curve after applying matrix transformation to all points in solution set to the original be given by the determinant?

How would one prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be more elementarily shown without appeal to the change of variables formula, which necessitates the Radon-Nikodym derivative, the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, and that the volume of a ball scales by the determinant, which is mildly circular.

The gist of the proof is this: given a linear map $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$, it admits a (insert your favourite decomposition here) polar decomposition $T=RU$ for a positive symmetric matrix $R$ and a unitary matrix $U$. It can be shown that for any set $E\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ and any unitary/orthogonal (same thing, in $\Bbb R$) matrix $U$ that $\mu^\ast(UE)=\mu^\ast(E)$ and then $E$ is measurable iff. $UE$ is. Similarly, if $D$ is a diagonal matrix we have $\mu^\ast(DE)=|\det D|\mu^\ast(E)$ and $DE$ is measurable iff. $E$ is measurable.

By the spectral theorem, $R$ has an orthogonal decomposition $QDQ^\ast$ with $Q$ orthogonal, $D$ diagonal, hence $T=RU=QD(Q^\ast U)$ ($Q^\ast U$ is also orthogonal) and for any measurable $E$: $$\begin{align}\mu(TE)&=\mu(QD(Q^\ast U)E)\\&=\mu(D(Q^\ast U)E)\\&=|\det D|\mu((Q^\ast U)E)\\&=|\det D|\mu(E)\\&=|\det T|E\end{align}$$

[Source](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf) for further reading and fuller proofs (as well as related introductory measure theory notes).

This assumes you know more linear algebra than you do measure theory, but I believe that this is easier to fully understand than the change of variables formula is. Hopefully some of the results such as rotation-invariance are intuitive even if the proof is hard to swallow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! In fact you can generalize that to any measurable set. The proof uses some elementary measure theory, a little linear algebra (polar decomposition of a matrix) and the fact that there exists a unique translation invariant measure on the Borel set of $\mathbb R^n$ up to a multiplication with a constant. This should all be covered in a book on measure theory as a part of the even more general transformation theorem (substitution theorem for multiple integrals).

Comment: What is the name of the theorem

Comment: This is just "change of variables" formula for 2-D integral.